# CSOM Javascript - when executing query on multiple lists getting error - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, csom

Is here any SharePoint expert, who can help me find out, why I am getting error on lists queries?

I am trying to fetch data from multiple list asynchronously, but I am getting following error: `The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`

My code looks like this:

```
function loadAllData() {
    loadTeam();
    loadTasks();    

    loadTaskTypes();
}
```

Where load functions looks like:

```
function loadTeam() {
    retrieveListItemsInclude(teamListProperties);
}
function loadTasks() {
    retrieveListItemsInclude(tasksListProperties);
}
...
```

And `retrieveListItemsInclude` function looks like:

```
function retrieveListItemsInclude(listProperties) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listProperties.listName);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>');

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    var includeListProperties = buildInclude(listProperties);
    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Title,ID)');

    switch(listProperties.listName) {
        case 'Task list':
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){ onTaskQuerySucceeded(listProperties); }, failCallback);
            break;
        case 'Task types list':
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){ onTaskTypesQuerySucceeded(listProperties); }, failCallback);
            break;
        ...
        case 'Team list':
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){ onTeamQuerySucceeded(listProperties); }, failCallback);
            break;
    }
}
```

And finally success callbacks look like:

```
function onTasksQuerySucceeded(listProperties) {

    var tasks = [];

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        var task = {};

        task.id = oListItem.get_item('ID');
        task.title = oListItem.get_item('Title');

        tasks.push(task);
    }

    console.log("Tasks loaded.");
}
```

When running `loadAllData()` function, I get above error, when calling `collListItem.getEnumerator()` in all of success callbacks, but the last.

This means, if I call `loadTeam(); loadTasks(); loadTaskTypes();` in `loadAllData()`, I get error in first two success callbacks, but `loadTaskTypes()` will execute properly.

Why is this happening? In `retrieveListItemsInclude(listProperties)`, I create local `clientContext` for every request to SharePoint list... why are the calls interfering?

When I used jQuery promises to chain calls `loadTeam(); loadTasks(); loadTaskTypes();` one after another, all data loaded without error.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, but your problem is still in JavaScript scopes :) ... specifically:

```
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
```

When the success call back comes through, the references have gotten messed up because the second function call overrode the colListItem (which is on the global scope) from first call.

Since you're already using listProperties as a unique variable you can utilize that further. Change the three lines to the following:

```
listProperties.colListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery)
var includeListProperties = buildInclude(listProperties);
clientContext.load(listProperties.collListItem, 'Include(Title,ID)');
```

Inside your success call back:

```
function onTasksQuerySucceeded(listProperties) {
    var tasks = [];
    var listItemEnumerator = listProperties.collListItem.getEnumerator();
    //rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: btw... I've created a library that does all of this creates reusable wrapper around CSOM, check it out here: https://github.com/monzerhijazi/SpUtil

Comment: Many thanks, you have got sharp eye :-) Finally it work. And I will definitely check your library.

Comment: @onzur Would the library also allow me to take a returned value from one list and query another list?

Comment: @Si8 Yes, you have to get the first item and in the success callback get the item from the other list.
var list1 = new SpListUtil("list1_title")
var list2 = new SpListUtil("list2_title")
list.getItemById(1, {
    success: function(item1){
         list2.getItemById(item1.field, {
               success: function(item2) {  console.log(item2.field) }
         }
    }
});

Comment: I tried that and on the second call, it gave me an error `SP.js:2 Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`

Comment: @Si8 can you paste your code?

Comment: Couldn't paste it here but here is where I pasted for you to check... https://jsfiddle.net/fx00x1mj/1/ Thank you.

Comment: @Si8 Hi, this should be its own stack exchange question :) I wasn't able to spot anything on the first run. Could you please open another question for this and also note which line the error you pasted appears. Also put a console.log in the error function listener: onQueryFailed. That should give us enough to help out

Comment: What should be inside the console.log? There is no line of error from the browser, just doesn't do anything, except the error I wrote earlier. Thanks.